# Spring 4.2.X HibernateTemplate and SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, sqlexception

As per [url](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-SQLExceptionTranslator), I can add the `SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator` only on `jdbcTemplate`.

But I am using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate` which do not support this exception translator. `hibernate3` had the support of this exception translator but not `hibernate4`.

Can someone suggest another way to handle the `SQLErrorCodes` in `Spring`'s `HibernateTemplate`

-- Hanumant